# Is the word "indeed" being properly used in the following passage?

Tags: word-usage

**Scene 1**

> Yuki laughed. "You know, sometimes I wonder if you live in the same
>   city as the rest of us."

**Scene 2**

> "That's right," Takeshi suddenly said. "Did you feel the earthquake
>   last night?"
>
> Eri stared at Takeshi with her lips slightly parted. *You too?* She
>   could barely believe it. It was the second time someone had asked her the question. *Am I the only one who didn't feel the earthquake? she wondered. Am I **indeed**
>   living in the same city as everyone else?*

As you can see Eri is repeating what Yuki told her on **Scene 1**. Is it correct to use **indeed** in this case?

Comment: 'Indeed' is merely being used as an emphasiser, a pragmatic marker showing the seriousness with which she is assessing her insensitivity, in 'Am I indeed living in [the] same city as everyone else?' Alternatives would be 'Am I _really_ living in [the] same city as everyone else?' and 'I have to ask myself - **Am** I living in [the] same city as everyone else!?' Obviously, she's speaking metaphorically, not geographically.

Comment: I do understand what causes your confusion, but yes, this is perfectly normal usage

Comment: Try substituting _really_ for _indeed_ and see if that clears up the confusion. You could also do the same with _not_. All three would essentially mean the same thing: _I'm in the same city as everyone else; how come I didn't feel it?_

Comment: You may have to tell us more as to why you think *indeed* may be incorrect, so we know what really is bugging you. By the way, yes, the use of *indeed* in the given sentence is correct and nothing unusual at all about it.

Comment: @Kris Well, as it usual in creative writing. It just didn't *feel* right to me.

Comment: janoChen, for the old-timers, it is much more familiar: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=indeed%2Creally&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=16&smoothing=3&share=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This picture](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=indeed,really&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=16&smoothing=3&share=) may not be worth a thousand words but may serve as a possible answer:

[image]

1. *Really* may have occurred in other senses than *indeed* in some of the sentences -- so that *really* is likely to have been unduly uppped.
2. The preference for *really* over *indeed* appears to have occurred around 1907-08.
3. We still read the classics, though, don't we?

Comment: Thanks you for the comments on the ngrams image. Ngrams presents numbers so it looks so official and respectable, but it may count different things than expected, and your comments point that out (there is the tendency in presenting an ngram to ignore the nuances).

Answer (score 0):

"Am I really living in the same city .." sounds more proper English-wise, but indeed has its own indeedic charm, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

*Really* and *indeed* each would be as correct as the other in place of your **indeed**, but neither is quite right at that point.  Slightly abstractly, the sequence you have is:

> Yuki to Eri:  “I wonder X”
>   Takeshi to Eri:  “Did you Y?”
>   Eri to self:  “I didn't Y.  Am I indeed X?”

Plainly, Eri would ask herself  “Am I indeed *not* X?” instead of “Am I indeed X?”.  One *can* use phrasings like  “Am I indeed not”, “Am I really not”, “Am I not indeed” and “Am I not really”, but none of them flow particularly well.  An [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Am+I+indeed+not%2CAm+I+really+not%2CAm+I+not+indeed%2CAm+I+not+really&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) for *Am I indeed not,Am I really not,Am I not indeed,Am I not really* shows no incidence of  “Am I indeed not”.

I included phrases “Am I not indeed” and “Am I not really” in the ngrams, even though opposite or somewhat opposite in meaning to the intended meaning.  That is, one asks  “Am I not indeed X” when coming to realize X applies after thinking it doesn't, where you want Eri to begin to think X does not apply after thinking it does.  (For “Am I not really X”, the case is less clear; it can be taken either way.)